# Wikipedia LATITUDE and LONGITUDE using XML XPATHS (in Python)

Tags: python, xpath, xml-parsing, geocoding

I'm trying to get the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE from a (random) Wikipedia entry.

```
wiki_coordinates(website)
coordinates = website.xml.find('.//*[@id="coordinates"]/')
```

Here is the HTML is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle (latitude and longitude)

There are two "interesting" sections of the HTML

```
<span class="latitude">47°36′35″N</span> <span class="longitude">122°19′59″W</span>
```

and

```
<span class="geo-dec" title="...">47.60972°N 122.33306°W</span>
```

The problem is that each wikipedia entry has different xpaths (or missing).

For example:

```
XPath =  ".//*[@id="coordinates"]/span/span/a/span[1]/span"
XPath = ".//*[@id="coordinates"]/span/a/span[3]/span[1]"
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: Sounds like `index.find` might return other falsey values.

Comment: Agree with @khelwood for lack of more information on the incoming data. Can you post the value of `th` in an `if index.find("th/a") is not None` branch? If it's an empty string, `0`, `None`, or `False`, then you've got your answer.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, I clarified what the question is about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to index the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE directly (from the top of Wikipedia) there are two ways to do this.

```
coordinates = website.xml.find('.//*[@class="geo-dec"]').text
```

or

```
latitude = website.xml.find('.//*[@class="latitude"]').text
longitude = website.xml.find('.//*[@class="longitude"]').text
```

Hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath expression and see if it works on these pages:

```
//span[@id="coordinates"]//span[@class="geo-dec"]//text()
```

Comment: Thanks...!     coordinates = website.xml.find('.//*[@class="geo-dec"]') did work.. let me test your idea as well on a few pages (I'm going to check "Seattle" and "Singapore")